# Key down functions

Tags: c++

Hey how do I make this in C++:
I have a variable, and when I press the key `'+'` it should increase by one, but when I press and hold the key for more than 500ms, the variable should start increasing by 5 every 500ms while I am still holding the button down, and it should stop when I release it.
I know of `getActiveKeyState()` function, but I can't seem to make it work the way I want.
How do I into this?

Comment: *What* `getActiveKeyState` function? You mean `GetAsyncKeyState`?

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are talking or asking about, by means of any c++ standards!

Comment: C++ doesn't know anything about keyboards.  Your operating system and application type are not minor details.

Comment: I mean this: Say x=1. When I press +, it should be x=2, but if I press and hold +, then after 500ms x should start increasing by 5 every 500ms.

Comment: I am using the __getchar() function from conio.h on windows

Comment: @user3720425 To rephrase Hans: **C++ doesn't know anything about keyboards**! `conio.h`, windows?!? May be [you should give more tags and context](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24110318/edit) for your _question_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about native C++ functions but it's doable with SFML libraries.

```
if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed){
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Add))
            {
                //start counter
                if(count < 5) sum++;          
                else
                 sum+=5;
            }
        }
```

You can do the same thing with WinApi but in both cases you'll need to use multithreading/multiprocessing for your counter, or find another way to sync your code.
You could try adding `Sleep(500)` which will sleep your thread for 500ms or something similar.